# map function not displaying data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

models/docs.js is for fetching api url from backend

```
const doc = {
    baseUrl: window.location.href.includes("localhost") ?
    "http://localhost:1337" :
    "",
    getallDocs: async function getallDocs() {
        console.log(window.location.href);

        const response = await fetch(`${doc.baseUrl}/docs`);

        const docs = await response.json();

        return docs.data;

    }
};

export default doc;
```

documents.js
i want to list of the titles that are available from database into a drop down but no data is displayed.

```
const [currentDoc, setCurrentDoc] = useState({});
useEffect(() =>{
  (async () => {
        const allDocs = await docsModel.getallDocs();
        setCurrentDoc(allDocs);
        // console.log(allDocs);
      })();
}, []);

return (
    <select>
      <option>Choose a document</option>
      {currentDoc?.map((doc, index) =>
              <option value={index} key={index}>{doc.title}</option>
      )}
    </select>
);
```

Comment: what gets printed to the console in console.log(allDocs)? is currentDoc an array or an object?

Comment: `map` function is for the array type. your `currentDoc` is an object

Comment: It showed undefined

Comment: it seems your getallDocs functions does not work, try to print inside it the response and docs objects

Comment: Your naming is confusing. You initialize `currentDoc` as an object, implying a single document, but then you `setCurrentDoc(allDocs)`, which would infer you're setting the `currentDoc` to multiple documents with an array.

Answer (score 0):

You defined currentDoc as object when using useState hook. Since .map() is for arrays, you should:

```
const [currentDoc, setCurrentDoc] = useState([]);
```

Keep in mind this is true if type of return docs.data is an array and not an object, if it is an object you need to convert it to an array